# Bug: React.js modifying css variable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I've used a string as a css variable in React.js but React modify this string `http://10.0.1.8/` to `http://100.10.8/`

[image]

How can i solve this?

Here is my code:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {

  render() {
   const testVar = {'--test-var' : 'http://10.0.1.8/'}
    return <div style={testVar}>Hello World</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Huh. I didn't believe you, but sure enough, I'm seeing the same thing: https://i.imgur.com/IBVCZxg.png [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wd3syz) Seems like a bug.

Comment: Actually, this appears to be a <del>browser quirk</del> [bug in Chrome]: https://i.imgur.com/Dcpy5tm.png https://jsbin.com/marujezuqa/1/edit?html,js,output I guess it's not React's fault, but I'm still not sure what's going on O.o Doesn't happen in Firefox: https://i.imgur.com/4OZP3GI.png nor Edge https://i.imgur.com/89dgoX5.png

Comment: Sounds like this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827521